# PayPal Buy Now Button - dropdown quantites

Tags: php, jquery, paypal, drop-down-menu

is it possible to customize a PayPal Buy Now button with a dropdown where client can choose quantity?

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="my_code">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/WEBSCR-640-20110401-1/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/WEBSCR-640-20110401-1/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Sure, it's possible. What code have you got so far? Do you know much JavaScript? Any JavaScript libraries available on your page?

Comment: @Alex Until now I have code for a simple Buy Now button. I use jQuery.

Comment: @morandi I've edited your tags. As for your question, the answer is *yes*. Are you really wanting the code to do this? People will be more willing to help you if you show what you have came up with so far.

Comment: @Alex I've added the code for a simple buy now button

Comment: Actually I think this is easy?! Just adding a seelct box for quantity?!

<select name="quantity"> 
  <option value="1">1 Credit
  <option value="2">2 Credits
  <option value="3">3 Credits
</select>

Comment: yup: http://jsfiddle.net/ampersand/3xyhD/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes, I'd almost say 'of course'.

Have a look at https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables to see which variables are accepted in a Website Payments Standards-type button. It seems you need the 'quantity' variable, so all you need to is create an option-select list:

```
<select name="quantity">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<!-- Etcetera.. -->

</select>
```